# Having trouble getting 2nd Nginx site on the same Ubuntu server to work correctly and complete acme challenge

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

Having some trouble getting a 2nd nginx block live - can't get the domain to point to the correct root folder and the Let's Encrypt Acme challenge is failing (probably related problems).

The server is Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm using it as a sandbox to work on sites.

Here is the sites available conf for the site that is just redirecting to the nginx default page

```
server {
root /var/www/boothslop.online;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html
servername boothslop.online www.boothslop.online;
location = /favicon.ico { lognotfound off; accesslog off; }
location = /robots.txt { lognotfound off; accesslog off; allow all; }
location ~* .(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
expires max;
lognotfound off;
}
location / {
#tryfiles $uri $uri/ =404;
tryfiles $uri $uri/ /index.php$isargs$args;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Here is the sites available conf for the site that is working correctly both for lets encrypt and finding the correct root folder when the domain is accessed.

```
server {
root /var/www/webtest.tech;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html
servername webtest.tech www.webtest.tech;
location = /favicon.ico { lognotfound off; accesslog off; }
location = /robots.txt { lognotfound off; accesslog off; allow all; }
location ~* .(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
expires max;
lognotfound off;
}
location / {
#tryfiles $uri $uri/ =404;
tryfiles $uri $uri/ /index.php$isargs$args;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/webtest.tech/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/webtest.tech/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
if ($host = www.webtest.tech) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = webtest.tech) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name webtest.tech www.webtest.tech;
}
```

This is the error I get from the Acme challenge

```
 Domain: www.boothslop.online
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.boothslop.online/.well-known/acme-challenge/G13Ou7X8U-KMQVvT_ExNvAfK5cF-jHkobGp7hyqw8ac
   [192.34.60.43]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not
   Found</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n<center><h1>404
   Not Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>"
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Few questions. Did you do a `nginx reload`? Is the conf file enabled? Did you run a `nginx -t`

Comment: @ShawnC. I tried restarting and stop / starting the nginx service - I did run nginx -t and there were no errors

Comment: Is the config linked?

Comment: @ShawnC. It is linked to sites enabled and shows up in that folder

Answer (score 0):

The error `404 Not Found` means it couldn't find the following file:

> http://www.boothslop.online/.well-known/acme-challenge/G13Ou7X8U-KMQVvT_ExNvAfK5cF-jHkobGp7hyqw8ac

Have you added the said file inside your public directory?

When doing responding to acme challenges, you're asked to add a text file in that address, along with what the content should be, so that it can run verification

Run the command again and it'll ask you to save a file with a definite file name and contents. Create the folders in the following structure:

```
<public directory>
       - .well-known
             - acme-challenge
```

Add the text file inside the acme folder, then proceed with the verification.

Hope that helps!